# Generic parameter type

Tags: c#, generics, parameters

I have a question concerning a generic type parameter.

Let's say I have the following definitions in my domain model:

```
abstract class Entity<TId>
{
    public TId Id { get; private set; }
    /* ... */
}

class Person : Entity<long>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    /* ... */
}
```

Let's say now I want to create a method to view details of a person:

```
public void Details(long? id)
{
    if (!id.HasValue) {
        Error(...);
        return;
    }
    var person = PersonRepository.Get(id.Value);
    ShowPersonDetail(person);
}
```

Let's go further and say that **PersonRepository** is an specialization of **Repository**, so that its "Get" method is "automagically" implemented, to accept the correct strong-typed id argument (in this case, a `long` argument).

---

Now let's say one day I decide that **Person's Ids should be Guids**. What I want is to be able to change this ONLY in my Person class, and it will change everywhere else automatically. If I do so, in the code I have right now, the PersonRepository.Get() method won't need to be edited, but my Details() method will have to be changed.

I was looking for something like:

```
Details(Person.IdType id) { /*...*/ }
```

Oh, by the way, this "Details" method will be located in another assembly, if this might change anything...

but strongly-typed and it must accept either value types or reference types.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure if this is what you want. You can have the method take a `Func<Person,T>` and have it infer the types for you:

```
public T Get<T>(Func<Person,T> property) {
    return property(myPerson);
}
```

and call it with:

```
var id = PersonRepository.Get(p => p.Id);
```

The compiler is able to infer type of `T` from the lambda expression.

Comment: It's not exactly that, the Repository part is ok, without funcs. The problem is for other methods, outside the scope of my domain model. I will try something with lambda expressions though. Thanks!